# VNC android app which takes native control of touch as a mouse

Tags: linux, vnc, rom

I've been trying to install a linux distribution onto my android tablet for some time now and have done so but have recently stumbled upon a problem. When connecting the mouse, naturally the app does not support dragging windows or scrolling or right mouse click. I was wondering if there was any way to have these things supported by any VNC app. Either that or an alternative way to install linux as a rom.

Answer (score 1):

[VNC Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android&hl=en) from RealVNC is a bit pricey ($9.99) but probably has the best keyboard/mouse support of any VNC app on Android.

Comment: I've tried that one out and yeah I guess that KINDA works... But I am looking for a more native answer (although a great suggestion!). I think I might try and flash some type of linux kernal and see if I just cant go and work on that but I have no clue where to go from there.

Comment: I answer a question on SU, then it gets migrated back here. So much for trying to branch out of Android =P